# Table Aliases in FastReport (DataField Attribute)

Tags: mysql, delphi, fastreport

i have a SQL query in the form of:

```
Select * from table a
inner join table b
on a.id = b.id;
```

The Result of this SQL goes to FastReport.
Within FastReport, I have some `TfrxMemoView` with the Attribute "DataField".

I can now write the name of the column in "DataField" and get the Value back as long, the column name is unique.

How can I make aliases work for the "DataField" Attribute?
Something like: a.example

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand well. The format of data fields is `[<dataset>."<Field Name>"]`. In your case if the dataset (your query) is named "a" then the data field in Fast report will be `[a."FieldName"]`.
Or  I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may set fields aliases for TfrxDBDataset (right click on the TfrxDBDataset in the IDE -> menu item "Edit Fields Aliases..." or set TfrxDBDataset.FieldAliases)